# Any compatibility issues opening VS 2015 Enterprise projects in VS 2015 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I want to start using Xamarin for a personal project at home using VS 2015 Community.  I would also like to be able to work on it on my off-time at work.. but I have VS 2015 Enterprise installed on my machine at work.

As long as I don't use any professional/enterprise features in my project, will there be any compatibility issues sharing the project between versions of VS?

Comment: Nope! You should be fine as long as you don't enable Enterprise level features or have them present in your `.csproj`.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I didn't expect to get a response so quickly.  You should post as an answer instead of a comment so I can credit you :)